# Troubleshooting an op-amp for amplifying a low voltage AC input

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, amplifier, troubleshooting

I am trying to amplify a low voltage AC input with a gain close to 5. It has a 0 DC offset and about 300 mV of AC amplitude, at 250 kHz. This is my first venture into electrical engineering and I’m having a good time, but alas, my first circuit does not work.

After doing some research on op-amps, I bought a [NJM072D](https://www.njr.com/semicon/PDF/NJM072_NJM072B_NJM082_NJM082B_E.pdf) because it has enough gain bandwidth product & slew rate. But for some reason, after placing it in a non-inverting configuration with a 0-5 V supply, I’m getting a constant 3.4 V at the output.

I saw [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/132509/effect-of-non-inverting-op-amp-on-the-ac-and-dc-components-of-the-input), so I decided to put a capacitor & resistor at the input, but the problem still persists.

So then I went back to you guys and found [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286788/operational-amplifier-ua741cp-reading-the-datasheet). And I think I’m having a similar problem?

The common mode voltage is +/- 10V on the data sheet and it was supplied +/-15V, so am I correct in saying that this op-amp will only accept inputs within 5 V of either side of the power supply? Why  does this requirement exist? I have a 0-30 V power supply, so can I simply use that to power then op-amp and then offset the input to be above +5V and below +25V?

Here is my schematic: [image]

Comment: You Don't need capacitor.  Besides what's the input voltage rage??  Like 0-2 volt, or -1 to +1

Answer (score 1):

The minimum operating voltage for the op-amp you chose is 8 volts. You are running on 5 volt. Looking at other parameters in the data sheet that device is totally unsuited for what you want and even on a supply as low as 8 volts you would have no guaranteed input common mode voltage range.

Looking at your schematic just in case, and I see you have the +Vin pin biased at 0 volts - at the very least, for amplification of an AC signal this would need to be biased midrail. Choose a better op-amp suited for low voltage supplies and bias +Vin correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can you tell me how you came up with 8 V as the minimum operating voltage? I’m not seeing how you got that from the data sheet.

Comment: From the first page - "Features: supply voltage +/- 4V to +/- 18V."

Comment: I see. So it needs at least an 8 V voltage difference to operate.

Comment: Just get another 5 V supply so you have +5 on V+ and -5 on V- and your non inverting Vin can stay biased at 0 V